# I can not found blade from resources. But website working

Tags: laravel

`@section('contents') <app-employee-list></app-employee-list> @endsection`

How I can get the full html structure form this? I can not found full code. but website is working.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a vue component, you can find it in this path
**resources/js/components**

OR it may be a laravel component, you can find it in this path
**resources/views/components**